# Adding files with Active Storage deleted the previous files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I am trying to add file uploads to my Rails 6 app and Active Storage.  I followed this guide (https://gorails.com/episodes/direct-uploads-with-rails-active-storage)

It works perfect except that when you update the parent record and add additional flies all the previous ones are purged.  Do you need to customize your controller or am I missing some simple configuration option here?

Comment: Just a single model in my app. I added has_many_attached :files

Comment: I will when I get to the office. It’s copy and pasted line for line from that screencast. I added files: [ ] to the params.  It works perfectly for both direct and non-direct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue in Rails 6.0.0rc1

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/36374

I think they'll fix this via a config variable if I understood well.

Comment: @DanTappin Sadly I haven't found any yet

Comment: I downgraded to Rails 5.  Also many gems are not ready for v6.  I am also going to add a wrapper Model to for attachments and use a single attachment.  I can then add a description field, notes, comments etc. to the attachment.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a bug but intended behavior, and the behavior is still the same in Rails 7.0. The behavior can be changed on application level, by adding

```
config.active_storage.replace_on_assign_to_many = false
```

to `config/application.rb`.

**UPDATE**: This configuration option is [already deprecated](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7-0-stable/activestorage/CHANGELOG.md) in Rails 7.0, and will be removed in Rails 7.1. The apps will behave as if the option is set to true, and the decision to append or replace has to be made individually for each action. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71990877/2186942) are some good viewpoints on how to do that.