# Rails Active Storage - Keep Existing Files / Uploads?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I have a Rails model with:

```
has_many_attached :files
```

When uploading via Active Storage by default if you upload new files it deletes all the existing uploads and replaces them with the new ones.

I have a controller hack from this which is less than desirable for many reasons:

[What is the correct way to update images with has_many_attached in Rails 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59803964/what-is-the-correct-way-to-update-images-with-has-many-attached-in-rails-6)

Is there a way to configure Active Storage to keep the existing ones?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Looks like there is a [configuration](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#config-active-storage-replace-on-assign-to-many) that does exactly that

```rb
config.active_storage.replace_on_assign_to_many = false
```

Unfortunately it is deprecated according to current rails source code and it will be [removed in Rails 7.1](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.2.3/activestorage/lib/active_storage/attached/model.rb#L150)

> `config.active_storage.replace_on_assign_to_many` is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 7.1. Make sure that your code works well with `config.active_storage.replace_on_assign_to_many` set to `true` before upgrading.
> To append new attachables to the Active Storage association, prefer using `attach`.
> Using association setter would result in purging the existing attached attachments and replacing them with new ones.

It looks like explicite usage of `attach` will be the only way forward.

So one way is to set everything in the controller:

```rb
def update
  ...
  if model.update(model_params)
    model.files.attach(params[:model][:files]) if params.dig(:model, :files).present?
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

If you don't like to have this code in controller. You can for example override default setter for the model eg like this:

```rb
class Model < ApplicationModel
  has_many_attached :files

  def files=(attachables)
    files.attach(attachables)
  end
end
```

Not sure if I'd suggest this solution. I'd prefer to add new method just for appending files:

```rb
class Model < ApplicationModel
  has_many_attached :files

  def append_files=(attachables)
    files.attach(attachables)
  end
end
```

and in your form use

```
  <%= f.file_field :append_files %>
```

It might need also a reader in the model and probably a better name, but it should demonstrate the concept.

Comment: This is an excellent answer!  I actually came across the controler solution but the new method idea is WAY better. 

Comment: If I do this in the controller, then all my new files will be added twice. I am guessing one with the `.attach` method, and also with the `model.update` method. Do we also need to make the `params[:model][:files] = nil` to prevent that?

Comment: Of course you cannot pass both. If you want to use `attach` explicitly you have to avoid passing `params[:model][:files]` to the `model.update`. You can do it eg by removing `:files` from the permitted params or by using different attribute. If you set `params[:model][:files]` to `nil` you have to be careful and do that after calling `attach` method and before attributes are passed to `model.update`.

Comment: not sure not working on my side, it will cause "stack level too deep"

Comment: @MadaAryakusumah I had the same issue, i've added my solution below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74207496/2728491

Comment: There's also this new configuration option, which may help. https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#config-active-storage-multiple-file-field-include-hidden

Answer (score 5):

The solution suggested for overwriting the writer by @edariedl **DOES NOT WORK** because it causes a `stack level too deep`

### 1st solution

Based on ActiveStorage source code [at this line](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/1562651e5fb02d7687ffe13498c0cc3aee9249f0/activestorage/lib/active_storage/attached/model.rb#L157-L160)

You can override the writer for the `has_many_attached` like so:

```rb
class Model < ApplicationModel
  has_many_attached :files

  def files=(attachables)
     attachables = Array(attachables).compact_blank

    if attachables.any?
      attachment_changes["files"] =
        ActiveStorage::Attached::Changes::CreateMany.new("files", self, files.blobs + attachables)
    end
  end
end
```

### Refactor / 2nd solution

You can create a model concern that will encapsulate all this logic and make it a bit more dynamic, by allowing you to specify the `has_many_attached` fields for which you want the **old** behaviour, while still maintaining the new behaviour for newer `has_many_attached` fields, should you add any after you enable the new behaviour.

in `app/models/concerns/append_to_has_many_attached.rb`

```rb
module AppendToHasManyAttached
  def self.[](fields)
    Module.new do
      extend ActiveSupport::Concern

      fields = Array(fields).compact_blank # will always return an array ( worst case is an empty array)

      fields.each do |field|
        field = field.to_s # We need the string version
        define_method :"#{field}=" do |attachables|
          attachables = Array(attachables).compact_blank

          if attachables.any?
            attachment_changes[field] =
              ActiveStorage::Attached::Changes::CreateMany.new(field, self, public_send(field).public_send(:blobs) + attachables)
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and in your model :

```rb
class Model < ApplicationModel
  include AppendToHasManyAttached['files'] # you can include it before or after, order does not matter, explanation below

  has_many_attached :files
end
```

NOTE: It does not matter if you `prepend` or `include` the module because the methods generated by ActiveStorage are added inside this [generated module](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/1562651e5fb02d7687ffe13498c0cc3aee9249f0/activerecord/lib/active_record/core.rb#L333-L341) which is called very early when you inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base` [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/1562651e5fb02d7687ffe13498c0cc3aee9249f0/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb#L13)

==> So your writer will always take precedence.

### Alternative/Last solution:

If you want something even more dynamic and robust, you can still create a model concern, but instead you loop inside the `attachment_reflections` of your model like so :

```rb
reflection_names = Model.reflect_on_all_attachments.filter { _1.macro == :has_many_attached }.map { _1.name.to_s } # we filter to exclude `has_one_attached` fields
# => returns ['files']
reflection_names.each do |name|
  define_method :"#{name}=" do |attachables|
  # ....
  end
end
```

**However I believe for this to work, you need to include this module after all the calls to your `has_many_attached` otherwise it won't work because the reflections array won't be fully populated** ( each call to has_many_attached appends to that array)

Comment: Dude you are awesome - solution 2 works like a charm - elegant and simple for multiple models using has_many_attached

Answer (score -1):

As of Rails 7, you can call `include_hidden: false` in your form to stop this happening.

```rb
<%= form.file_field :images, multiple: true, include_hidden: false %>
```

More details on the `file_field` documentation.

> :include_hidden - When multiple: true and include_hidden: true, the field will be prefixed with an  field with an empty value to support submitting an empty collection of files.

https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-file_field

Comment: Oh wait, the documentation says to use `include_hidden: true`, but that does the opposite of that we want.